# Matlab function which will perform the analysis of my system with respect to Control Theory.

Tags: systems-of-equations, matlab, control-theory

$x`(t)=Ax(t)+Bu(t)$

$y`(t)=Cx(t)$

I have three matrices. For example, the matrices are:
[image]

And using only one Matlab function I would like to get the following information:

1 Eigenvalues of the matrix A.

2 System modes.

3 ${e}^{A}$.

4 Whether or not the system is robust.

5 Resistance poles.

I am sure that all this is possible to get using only one function, but I do not know which one. Could you, please, help me find it.

Thank you.

Comment: How much experience do you have with Matlab? And with only one Matlab function you mean a function you can write yourself?

Comment: What are "resistance poles"? I have never heard of that term and I am unable to find anything control-related on that term using google... Also, whether a system is robust isn't really a question with a yes/no answer, as indicated by your question 4. And robustness is usually a property of a controlled system, however, your system seems to be open loop (i.e. has no controller)?